# Regex: Remove all before and after the second "-"

Tags: java, android, regex

Good day, I have `Strings`:

```
 "bus-nr-7b-Station-Yellow-Street",
 "bus-nr-8-Station-Lewis-Street",
 "train-nr-9-Station-Yield-Street",
 "bus-nr-10-Station-Harrow",
 "train-nr-10a-Station-Booki",
 "train-nr-11-Station-Horope",
 "bus-nr-12-Station-Erstin",
 "bus-nr-13-Station-Green-Street",
 "train-nr-13ab-Station-Final-Station",
```

At the end I would like:

```
 "B:7b",
 "B:8",
 "T:9",
 "B:10",
 "T:10a",
 "T:11",
 "B:12",
 "B:13",
 "T:13ab",
```

So, I would like to replace all before the second `-` with `B:` or `T:`, and remove all after the third `-`. How can I implement that using regex?

Comment: Which language/tool?

Comment: Java/Android is it important?

Comment: What code have you written yourself to try and solve this? And what problems did you run into?

Comment: Only one thing, what I have, that `\d.*` I found number, but how to stop before `-` I don't know. I know how to replace `train` or `bus` to `T:` or `B:` using String.replace() method, but how to implement using regex I don`t know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's faster to not use regex in your case:

```
String foo = "bus-nr-7b-Station-Yellow-Street";
String[] parts = foo.split("-");
String result = Character.toUpperCase(foo.charAt(0)) + ":" + parts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Match with:

```
^([bt])[^-]*-[^-]*-([^-]*)
```

Result:

```
match.group(1).toUpperCase() + ":" + match.group(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regular expressions for this.

```
for (String str : strings) {
  String prefix;
  if (str.startsWith("bus")) { prefix = "B"; }
  else if (str.startsWith("train")) { prefix = "T"; }
  else throw new AssertionError("Not bus or train");

  int firstDash = str.indexOf("-");
  int secondDash = str.indexOf("-", firstDash + 1);
  int thirdDash = str.indexOf("-", secondDash + 1);

  System.out.println(prefix + ":" + str.substring(secondDash, thirdDash));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assume `s` is one line of text.

- Assume the text in your file is valid.

  ```
   s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + ":" + s.split("-")[2])
  ```